# LOGIXML connection to Apache Derby DB

Tags: derby

I would like to create a connection between LogiXML and an Apache Derby DB. Does anybody know how I can do this? At first sight, it seems that LogiXML isn't capable with Apache Derby, I don't know if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this is really a question about LogiXML (whatever that is), more than about Derby. So perhaps tagging with Derby is not getting the attention of the right people (those who know LogiXML).